# Small, portable USB-C monitor with hub?

Tags: usb, monitors, hub

My phone does [this neat trick](https://www.samsung.com/us/business/products/mobile/phones/dex/) where I can plug it into a USB-C hub and it'll let me use an external monitor, keyboard, and mouse. This has inspired me and I think I would love a way to take advantage of this portably, maybe to hang out in more places and do light work or gaming.

I would love a small monitor, maybe 10-15 inches, which is gets video (and power would be nice) through USB-C, and which also has some USB-A ports on the back for a keyboard and mouse. Does such a thing exist yet?

Answer (score 1):

- [Elecrow AUS50024E](https://www.elecrow.com/10-1-inch-1920x1080-resolution-hdmi-vga-ips-ps3-ps4-gaming-screen-with-build-in-speakers-for-raspberry-pi-b-2b-3b-xbox-windows-7-8-10.html) (1920x1080 or [2560x1600 HDR](https://www.elecrow.com/10-1-inch-ips-2k-portable-display-supports-hdr-for-raspberry-pi-ps4-xbox-ns.html), 10.1") they have a big selection, visit their website. They make no mention of this working with Dex but do say:

  > Works perfectly for PS3, PS4, WiiU, XBOX360, Raspberry Pi 3, 2, & 1 Model B or B+, industrial equipment, car audio and video, car headrest, medical equipment display.
- The [GeChic 1503E Monitor](https://www.gechic.com/en-portable-monitor-onlap1503e-overview.html) (1920x1080, 15.6") specifically mentions that usability with smartphones is one of its abilities:

  > Enlarge Your Mobile Phone without Sacrificing Quality
  >   On-Lap 1503E is always your smartphone’s perfect match. Make sure your smartphone supports HDMI output and use the manufacturer’s adapter to output your mobile phone to On-Lap 1503E.
- The [GeChic 1101P Monitor](https://www.gechic.com/en-portable-monitor-onlap1101p-overview.html) (1920x1080, 11.6") has HDMI, and DisplayPort, it mentions it works with a Mac, no mention of smartphones, uses a battery pack (which is probably better than USB powered).
- The [GeChic 1102H Monitor](https://www.gechic.com/en-portable-monitor-onlap1102h-overview.html) (1920x1080, 11.6") has built-in battery that they claim lasts 4 1/2 hours.

See also: "[10 Best Portable Monitors](https://ca.bestreviews.guide/portable-monitors)".

It is also possible to use [Moverio BT-300](https://epson.com/For-Work/Wearables/Smart-Glasses/Moverio-BT-300-Smart-Glasses-%28AR-Developer-Edition%29-/p/V11H756020) glasses which simulate a 40" (at 2.5 m) or 320" (at 20 m) screen, they're U$800 but don't need a Dex; they can also be used to fly a drone (if that recoupes some of the cost).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've looked through these, but it's not clear from the product pages. Are they driven by USB-C? Like, for their video? That's kinda the main draw for me: having one USB-C cable from my phone to the monitor, then plug in the mouse/keyboard to the monitor's hub

Comment: I can do some more research tomorrow if needed, [I've found this so far, for the GeChic 1303i 13.3" 1080p Touchscreen](https://www.amazon.com/1303i-Touchscreen-Portable-Monitor-MiniDisplay/product-reviews/B00XK5A502/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_srvw_txt?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&sortBy=recent#R11X7RLIXHYDIH): "Mainly wanted as a monitor for the Samsung Galaxy Note9 w/Dex dock. The dock isn't able to supply the required power to the monitor, so an external USB power supply is used (the dock itself needs dedicated power as well). Works great, touchscreen fully functional. ...".